# Text shadow color hidden in the stylesheet

Tags: colors, stylesheet, css

Please observe this stylesheet: http://jsfiddle.net/VjhJ4/12/

If you hover your mouse over the anchored menu, you will see that there is a grey/white-ish shadow to the text. **Where can I change that shadow color?** I have searched the stylesheet everywhere without any succeed, but surely it must be hiding there somewhere.

I will paste the stylesheet here as well (although I advice checking the fiddle):

```
/*------------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------[RESET]------------------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------*/
.dd12:hover{
    background:#f00 !important;
}
.dd13:hover{
    background:green !important;
}
.dd14:hover{
    background:blue!important;
}

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; outline: 0; font-size: 100%; vertical-align: baseline; background: transparent; }

body { line-height: 1; }
ol, ul { list-style: none; }
blockquote, q {    quotes: none; }

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,q:before, q:after { content: ''; content: none; }

/* remember to define focus styles! */
:focus { outline: 0; }

/* remember to highlight inserts somehow! */
ins { text-decoration: none; }
del { text-decoration: line-through; }

/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }


/*------------------------------------------------*/
/*-----------------[BASIC STYLES]-----------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------*/

body { line-height: 20px; font-family:'Droid Sans',Arial,Verdana,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #48423f; background: url(images/header-bg.png); text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff; }

a { text-decoration: none; color: #00b7f3; }
a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
.clear { clear: both; }
.ui-tabs-hide { display: none; }
br.clear { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { padding-bottom: 5px; color: #48423F; letter-spacing: -1px; line-height: 1em; font-weight: normal; }
h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a { color: #48423F; }
h1 { font-size: 30px; }
h2 { font-size: 24px; }
h3 { font-size: 22px; }
h4 { font-size: 18px; }
h5 { font-size: 16px; }
h6 { font-size: 14px; }
p { padding-bottom: 10px; line-height: 24px; }
strong { font-weight: bold; color: #1c1c1c; }
cite, em, i { font-style: italic; }
pre, code { font-family: Courier New, monospace; margin-bottom: 10px; }
ins { text-decoration: none; }
sup, sub { height: 0; line-height: 1; position: relative; vertical-align: baseline; }
sup { bottom: 0.8em; }
sub { top: 0.3em; }
dl { margin: 0 0 1.5em 0; }
dl dt { font-weight: bold; }
dd  { margin-left: 1.5em;}
blockquote  { margin: 1.5em; padding: 1em; color: #666666; background: #e6e6e6; font-style: italic; border: 1px solid #dcdcdc; }
    blockquote p { padding-bottom: 0px; }

input[type=text],input.text, input.title, textarea, select { background-color:#fff; border:1px solid #bbb; padding: 2px; color: #4e4e4e; }
input[type=text]:focus, input.text:focus, input.title:focus, textarea:focus, select:focus { border-color:#2D3940; color: #3e3e3e; }
input[type=text], input.text, input.title, textarea, select { margin:0.5em 0; }
textarea { padding: 4px; }

img#about-image { float: left; margin: 3px 8px 8px 0px; }

.clearfix:after { visibility: hidden; display: block; font-size: 0; content: " "; clear: both; height: 0; }
* html .clearfix             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */

/*------------------------------------------------*/
/*---------------[MAIN LAYOUT INFO]---------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------*/

#top-header { border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff; position: relative; background: url(images/header-bg.png); }
    #top-header .container { min-height: 46px; }
    #top-shadow { background: url(images/top-shadow.png) repeat-x; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 7px; }
    #bottom-shadow { background: url(images/bottom-shadow.png) repeat-x; width: 100%; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; height: 4px; }
    .container { text-align: left; margin: 0 auto; width: 960px; position: relative; }
        #content { margin-bottom: 39px; }
            ul#top-menu { float: left; padding-left: 36px; }
            #search-form { float: right; background: url(images/search-bg.png) no-repeat; width: 167px; height: 27px; padding-right: 48px; margin-top: 11px; }
                #search-form #searchinput { background: none; border: none; float: left; margin: 5px 7px 0 5px; width: 116px; padding-left: 9px; font-size: 11px; color: #6f6967; }
                #search-form #searchsubmit { margin-top: 7px; margin-right: 7px; }
#content-area { background: #fafcfc url(images/content-area-bg.png); border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff; }        

        #top-stitch { background: url(images/top-stich.png) repeat-x bottom left; height: 7px; }
        #content-area .container { padding-top: 51px; }
            #logo-area { text-align: center; position: relative; padding-bottom: 37px; }
                p#slogan { font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Kreon', Arial, sans-serif; color: #9aa4a4; text-transform: uppercase; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ffffff; }
            #content { -moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px; border: 1px solid #e2e5e5; }

                #content-shadow { background: url(images/content-main-shadow.png) repeat-y; }
                    #content-top-shadow { background: url(images/content-top-shadow.png) repeat-x 0 1px; }
                        #content-bottom-shadow { background: url(images/content-bottom-shadow.png) repeat-x bottom left; }

                #inner-border { border: 1px solid #ffffff; background: #fff url(images/content-bg.png); /*height: 100%;*/ }
                    #inner-border, #content-shadow, #content-top-shadow, #content-bottom-shadow { -moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px; }

                    #second-menu { background: url(images/menu-bottom-bg.png) repeat-x bottom left; }    
                        ul#secondary-menu { padding-left: 29px; margin-top:-1px; }
                    #controllers { margin-bottom: 27px; margin-left: 23px; position: relative; }
                        #controllers #active_item { background: url(images/featured-arrow.png) no-repeat; position: absolute; top: -30px; left: 36px; width: 20px; height: 10px; z-index: 100; }
                        .controller { display:block; float:left; position:relative; margin-right: 21px; }
                            .controller a { display: block; }
                            .controller a.active { -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); box-shadow: 0 0 6px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); }
                                .controller span.overlay { background:url(images/controller-overlay.png) no-repeat; display:block; height:54px; left:0px; position:absolute; top:0px; width:95px; }
                    .recent-from { float: left; width: 317px; }
                        .recent-middle { width: 318px !important; }
                        .recent-last { width: 321px !important; }
                            .recent-last .recent-content { background: none !important; }

                        .main-title { background:url(images/title-bg.png) repeat-x; height: 42px; line-height: 42px; font-size: 13px !important; text-transform: uppercase; color: #48423f; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ffffff; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; padding-bottom: 0; font-family: 'Droid Sans',Arial,Verdana,sans-serif !important; }
                            #comment-wrap .main-title { margin: 0 -37px 12px -39px; }
                        .recent-content { background:url(images/recent-content-bg.png) repeat-y top right;margin-top: -1px; padding: 29px 32px 38px 35px; }
                        .last { background: none; }
                            .block-post { margin-bottom: 7px; }
                                .block-post .thumb { display:block; float:left; position:relative; margin-right: 17px; }
                                    .block-post .thumb span.overlay { background:url(images/post-overlay.png) no-repeat; display:block; height:41px; left:0px; position:absolute; top:0px; width:41px; }
                                .block-post h3.title { font-family: 'Kreon', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ffffff; }    
                                    .block-post h3.title a { text-decoration: none; color: #48423f; }
                                .block-post     p.meta-info { color: #b8c2c2; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ffffff; margin-top: -4px; }
                                    .block-post     p.meta-info a { text-decoration: none; color: #8c9c9c; }
                                        .block-post     p.meta-info a:hover { color: #444c4c; }
                            a.more { background:url(images/more.png) no-repeat right bottom; color:#8c9c9c; display:block; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ffffff; padding-right:6px; text-decoration:none; height: 35px; line-height: 35px; margin-left: 16%; margin-right: 16%; text-align: center;}
                            a.more:hover { color:#111111; }
                                a.more span { background:url(images/more.png) no-repeat; display:block; height: 35px; padding-left: 6px; }
                            .post a.more { float: right; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; }
                                .post a.more span { padding-left: 12px; padding-right: 4px; }
                        #left-area { float: left; width: 634px; }
                        #sidebar { float: left; width: 322px; }
                            #entries { background:url(images/recent-content-bg.png) repeat-y 633px 0px; padding: 31px 38px 27px; }
                                .entry { margin-bottom: 10px; }
                                    .entry .thumb, .photostream .thumb { display:block; float:left; position:relative; margin-right: 14px; margin-top: 5px; }
                                    .photostream .thumb { margin-right: 9px; margin-bottom: 9px; }
                                        .entry .thumb span.overlay, .photostream .thumb span.overlay { background:url(images/entry-overlay.png) no-repeat; display:block; height:68px; left:0px; position:absolute; top:0px; width:68px; }
                                        .photostream .thumb span.overlay { background:url(images/entry-overlay.png) no-repeat !important; height:68px !important; width:68px !important; }
                                        .latest .thumb span.overlay, body.single .thumb span.overlay, body.page .thumb span.overlay { background:url(images/single-overlay.png) no-repeat !important; width: 201px; height: 201px; }
                                    .entry h3.title, h1.title { font-family: 'Kreon', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 20px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ffffff; }
                                    h1.title { color: #48423f; font-size: 30px; }
                                        .entry h3.title a { text-decoration: none; color: #48423f; }
                                    .entry p.meta-info { color: #b8c2c2; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ffffff; margin-top: -2px; margin-bottom: -8px; }
                                    .entry p.meta-info a { text-decoration: none; color: #8c9c9c; }
                                        .entry p.meta-info a:hover { color: #444c4c; }
                                    .entry div.post-meta { background: url(images/meta-separator.png) repeat-x; margin: 8px 0 14px; }
                                        .entry div.post-meta p.meta-info { background: url(images/meta-separator.png) repeat-x bottom left; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 6px 0 8px; }

                                    .latest .thumb { display:block; float:left; position:relative; margin-right: 28px; }
                                        .latest .thumb span.overlay { background:url(images/entry-latest-overlay.png) no-repeat !important; display:block; height:131px; left:0px; position:absolute; top:0px; width:131px; }
                                    .latest h3.title { font-family: 'Kreon', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 24px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ffffff; }    
                                        .latest h3.title a { text-decoration: none; color: #48423f; }
                                    .latest p.meta-info { color: #b8c2c2; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ffffff; margin-top: -2px; margin-bottom: -8px; }
                                    .latest p.meta-info a { text-decoration: none; color: #8c9c9c; }
                                        .latest p.meta-info a:hover { color: #444c4c; }    
                                    a.read-more { float: right; color:#b8c2c2; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ffffff; text-decoration:none; }
                                        a.read-more:hover { color:#111111; }    
                        .blog-entry { position: relative; width: 248px; padding-left: 32px; }
                            a.comments { background:url(images/comments-cloud.png) no-repeat; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 37px; height: 33px; font-weight: bold; color:#48423f; text-decoration: none; padding: 4px 0; text-align: center; }
                            .blog-entry h4.title { padding-left: 25px; padding-right: 33px; font-family: 'Kreon', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color:#48423f; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ffffff; }
                            .blog-entry p.meta-info { padding-left: 25px; padding-right: 33px; color:#b8c2c2; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ffffff; margin-top: -2px; }    
                                .blog-entry p.meta-info a { text-decoration: none; color: #8c9c9c; }
                                    .blog-entry p.meta-info a:hover { color: #444c4c; }
            #ad-720 { text-align: center; padding-bottom: 32px; }                                
        #bottom-stitch { background: url(images/top-stich.png) repeat-x bottom left; height: 7px; margin-bottom: 4px; }

        #breadcrumbs { background: url("images/title-bg.png") repeat-x; height: 42px; line-height: 42px; padding-left: 38px; }
            #breadcrumbs  a { color: #b9c5c5; }
            #breadcrumbs, #breadcrumbs  a:hover { color: #929e9e; text-decoration: none; }

        #main-content { position: relative; }    
            #index-top-shadow { background: url("images/content-top-shadow.png") repeat-x scroll 0 1px; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 6px; width: 100%; border-top: 1px solid #dee0e0; }

        .post ul, .comment-content ul { list-style-type: disc; padding: 10px 0px 10px 20px; }
        .post ol, .comment-content ol { list-style-type: decimal; list-style-position: inside; padding: 10px 0px 10px 2px; }
            .post ul li ul, .post ul li ol, .comment-content ul li ul, .comment-content ul li ol { padding: 2px 0px 2px 20px; }
            .post ol li ul, .post ol li ol, .comment-content ol li ul, .comment-content ol li ol  { padding: 2px 0px 2px 35px; }                        

    .fullwidth #left-area { width: 100%; }
        .fullwidth #entries { background: none; }
    body.page h1.title { margin-bottom: 8px; }

    .ad-468 { text-align: center; margin-bottom: 30px; }
    .ad-bottom { margin-top: 35px; margin-bottom: 6px; }

/*------------------------------------------------*/
/*---------------[DROPDOWN MENU]------------------*/
/*------------------------------------------------*/

ul#top-menu li { padding-right: 2px; background: url(images/menu-bg.png) repeat-y top right; }
    ul#top-menu a { font-size: 11px; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.7); padding: 16px 12px 10px; }
    ul#top-menu a:hover { color: #ebbe5e;}
    ul#top-menu > li.current_page_item > a { color: #ebbe5e !important; }

    ul#top-menu li ul, #mobile_menu { width: 170px !important; padding: 0; background: #161616 url(images/header-bg.png); top: 45px !important; -moz-box-shadow:3px 3px 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); -moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px; border-top-left-radius: 0px;-moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px; border-top-right-radius: 0px; -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px; -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px; -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px; z-index: 9999px; display: none; }
        ul#top-menu ul li, #mobile_menu li a { margin: 0 !important; padding: 10px 7px 10px 25px !important; background: url(images/top-menu-separator.png) repeat-x; }
        ul#top-menu ul li.first-item { background: none; }
            ul#top-menu ul li a, #mobile_menu a { padding: 0 !important; width: 138px; }

            ul#top-menu li:hover ul ul, ul#top-menu li.sfHover ul ul { top: -1px !important; left: 171px !important; -moz-border-radius: 8px; -webkit-border-radius: 8px; border-radius: 8px; }

    ul#top-menu li.menu-gradient { background: url("images/top-shadow.png") repeat-x; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 202px; height: 7px !important; }

ul#secondary-menu li { padding-right: 2px; background: url(images/secondary-menu-bg.png) repeat-y top right; }
    ul#secondary-menu a { font-size: 13px; color: #48423f; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold; padding: 22px 16px; }
    ul#secondary-menu a:hover { color: #000000;}
    ul#secondary-menu > li.current_page_item > a { color: #919e9e !important; }    

    ul#secondary-menu li ul, #category_mobile_menu { width: 360px !important; padding: 7px 0 10px; background: #fff url(images/content-bg.png); top: 55px !important; -moz-box-shadow:3px 3px 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); -moz-border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px; border-top-left-radius: 0px;-moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px; border-top-right-radius: 0px; -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px; -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px; -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px; z-index: 9999px; display: none; }
        ul#secondary-menu ul li, #category_mobile_menu li a { margin: 0 !important; padding: 8px 0 8px 30px !important; width: 150px; float: left; }
            ul#secondary-menu ul li a, #category_mobile_menu a { padding: 0 !important; }

            ul#secondary-menu li:hover ul ul, ul#secondary-menu li.sfHover ul ul { top: -8px !important; left: 180px !important; -moz-border-radius: 8px; -webkit-border-radius: 8px; border-radius: 8px; }
            ul#secondary-menu ul li.even-item { background: none; }
```

Can you find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's here - first rule in `[BASIC STYLES]`

```
body { 
    line-height: 20px; 
    font-family:'Droid Sans',Arial,Verdana,sans-serif; 
    font-size: 12px; 
    color: #48423f; 
    background: url(images/header-bg.png); 
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff; /* remove this */
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. That's your 2nd question today about this CSS file. I can see it gives you hard times :)

Comment: Yeah I was about to set my hair on fire but this solved everything, unless there will be more surprises tonight :P

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any way to make a custom text shadow for the menu presented in the fiddle? If I changed the current one, it changed everything in the site...

Comment: yes, apply the `text-shadow` to `ul#secondary-menu a` in the stylesheet